# Designing a trial where the null hypothesis should not be rejected

Tags: logistic, experiment-design

### Background

I'm currently designing a trail to compare the risk of radial artery occlusion between two medical treatments (standard of care versus new approach).

When performing cardiac catheterization, an instrument is inserted into the radial artery from which the catherization can be done.  Once the instrument is removed from the artery, a compression tool is used to stop bleeding from the artery.

Literature shows that the risk of radial artery occlusion (essentially, blockage of the artery so that the instrument can not be re-inserted once removed) increases as the size of the instrument increases from 4 mmto 6 mm using the standard compression technique.  A new compression approach has been developed and it is hypothesized that the risk of occlusion seen in increasing the diameter of the instrument is removed with use of this new compression tool.

### Design

In this trail, patients will be randomized to two levels:

1) Level one will be a randomization to a sheath size (one of 4 mm, 5 mm or 6 mm) at a 1:1 ratio (e.g. equal numbers in each group).  This variable will be treated as continuous.

2) Level two will be randomization to standard of care or new approach at a 1:1 ratio.

The outcome is binary (did the patient suffer radial artery occlusion post compression? Yes or No).

### Question

The investigators hypothesize that the new compression technique will be so beneficial as to remove all risk of occlusion associated with an increase of instrument diameter. Shown below is a hypothesis of how the risk will look (ignore the fact they risk is linear, this is purely for exposition).

[image]

One way to design the study is to make the intervention the reference group and then analyze a logistic regression model where the linear predictor is given by

$$ \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mbox{diameter} + \beta_2 \mbox{compression } + \beta_3 (\mbox{compression} \times \mbox{diameter}) $$

Here, compression is a binary variable and diameter is continuous. If the intervention group is made the reference group, then evidence for the hypothesis could be provided by failing to reject the null hypothesis that $\beta_1 \neq 0$.

Is this an appropriate way to go about analyzing the design provided we hypothesize the new intervention removes risk of occlusion associated with an increase in instrument diameter?  Or, would it be better to simply analyze the interaction model above, with compression standard of care as the reference group and then do a non-inferiority test of some sort?

Comment: Failure to reject the null doesn't establish the null. It would also seem extremely risky to assert the new compression treatment has zero risk; a single occlusion would disprove that claim - even if it was a much better treatment.

Comment: @Glen_b A) sure, it’s the whole “the absence of evidence...” bit. But could I make statements like “the new compression technique does not appear to be significantly worse than seeing 0 additional risk when increasing instrument diameter, up to non inferiority threshold delta” via a non-inferiority test? And B) the claim is not that the new technique has 0 risk. It’s that there is no *additional* risk when instrument size changes. Baseline risk always exists.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed the mention of noninferiority near the end there before. That makes sense. Sorry I seem to have misinterpreted a couple of the statements (and the plot) relating to the risk; thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Glen_b So does a non-inferiority test make sense in this application?

Comment: Yes, I think it does.